# Get latest success commit on GitLab Continuous Integration

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I´m working with my own GitLab and GitLab CI server. I´d like to get the latest success commit.

I just can get my latest build status off a branch from the URL:

```
      http://mygitlab.ci/projects/3/status?ref=master
```

I need that in order to deploy the latest success version of my repo, but I really don´t understand CI with own GitLab and there are not a lot of documentation.

**UPDATE**:

i.e. In the picture you can see the latest 3 commits and their status. I really need to get the latest success commit (763a3077).

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the 'last success commit'? The last commit ran all ci jobs successfully? I am pretty sure the api can provide you with the commit that, (see gitlab documentation: http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/api/commits.html)

Comment: I tried with the API but it's not working. when I try http://mygitlab.ci/projects/<project_id>/commits/<token>, I get a 404 error. I think that I´m not building the url correctly, but I checked everythng and I didn´t find a complete sample of url structure.

Comment: Have you tried using a a tool like postman?

Comment: I have tried with RESTClient and HTTPRequester (both of them are firefox extensions) but I receive the same (404)

Comment: I am not familiar with gitlab ci but isn't the url perhaps somthing like /api/3/projects/:id/commits

Comment: I tried with /api/v1/projects and it sent me a 403 response. Furthermore, this url is the only one sending a 403.

Comment: Looks like you need to pass credentials in the header or am apikey in the url. You can pass it in the url like so:
http://ci.example.com/api/v1/projects?private_token=QVy1PB7sTxfy4pqfZM1U&url=http://demo.gitlab.com/
 see: http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/api/README.html

Comment: The url http://mygitlab.ci/api/v1/commits?project_token=<my-project-token>&project_id=<my-project-id> work!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

Here I have the answer. The URL must be something like this:

```
  http://my.gitlabci/api/v1/commits?project_token=<my-project-token>&project_id=<my-project-id>
```

GET /commits

Parameters:

- project_id (required) - The ID of a project
- project_token (requires) - Project token
- page (optional)
- per_page (optional) - items per request (default is 20)

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html